# System.MissingMethodException Method not found: 'NUnit.Framework.Interfaces No tests found

Tags: nunit

I have just installed NUnit v3.5.0 and when I try to run existing tests I get the error below:

System.MissingMethodException
Method not found: 'NUnit.Framework.Interfaces.ITest NUnit.Framework.Api.NUnitTestAssemblyRunner.Load(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Collections.IDictionary)'.
No tests found.

any ideas more than welcome!! :)

Comment: Need more info. Did you actually recompile your tests against the NUnit 3.5 framework? How are you running your tests - with what runner and version?

Comment: Thanks Charlie, no I haven't, how do you actually recompile your tests against the NNUnit 3.5 framework ? I am running tests by clicking on the Test tab upper menu bar on Visual studio, specifically Test >> Run >> All Tests

Answer (score 1):

just found the problem, I was missing an extension, you need to install "NUnit 3 Test Adapter", by going to tools>>Extensions and Updates >> Online >> Search for : "NUnit 3 Test Adapter"